Matrix of a module over a complex polynomial ring
I'm having trouble with the following question:
Given a $\mathbb{C}[x]$ module of the form $M=\bigoplus_1^n\mathbb{C}[x]/(x-\lambda_i)^{n_i}$. what condition on the $\lambda_i$ ensures that $M$ is cyclic?
I know the structure theorem for modules over a polynomial ring $F[t]$ (with $F$ a field) states that any (finitely generated) module can be expressed as a direct sum $R/(d_i)$, where each $d_i$ is monic and divides $d_{i+1}$. I don't know exactly how to apply that to this problem, though.
Also, how does this connect to the diagonalization of the presentation of the module? Does the equivalency between linear operators on a vector space $V$ over $F$ and $F[t]$-modules have anything to do with its presentation matrix?
